# Error message "Failed status on line 98: 1. Aborting" while running zephyr host emulator

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, micro-ros

This is my first time setting up a micro-ROS and a ROS 2 dev environment, so I suspect there may be something obvious that I'm missing.

I'm attempting to run the Zephyr host emulator example in the micro-ROS tutorial [here](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/zephyr_emulator/) with ROS2 humble.

Effectively, I've installed `micro_ros_setup`, created/configured/built the firmware and installed `micro_ros_agent`. Then, when I run the zephyr app I see the error listed in the title, and I don't see any change in the output of the micro-ROS agent.

What I *think* I'm encountering is that the Zephyr app is unable to reach the micro-ROS agent, thus the "Failed status" error message.

From a third terminal I can see the port with `netstat`, so I don't believe this is a firewall issue since the host emulator and micro-ros agent are both running on the same machine.

```sh
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8888
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*                           78240/micro_ros_age
```

Inspecting the source code at `firmware/zephyr_apps/apps/ping_pong/src/main.c`, line 98, it appears as though `rclc_support_init()` is failing.

```c
    // create init_options
    RCCHECK(rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator));
```

Additionally, **should I see a node running and new topics listed when I run the micro-ROS agent?** I'm seeing neither and I wonder if that's the reason:

```sh
$ ros2 topic list
/parameter_events
/rosout
```

```sh
$ ros2 node list
```

#### Zephyr Tutorial

Below is a summary of Zephyr micro-ROS tutorial to show where I'm at and how I got here.

Start with micro_ros_setup

```sh
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash

# install micro_ros_setup in new workspace
git clone -b $ROS_DISTRO https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_setup.git src/micro_ros_setup

# rosdep & pip
sudo apt update && rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

# build micro_ros_setup and source it
colcon build
source install/local_setup.bash
```

Then the firmware workspace

```sh
# create fw ws
ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_firmware_ws.sh zephyr host

# configure build 
ros2 run micro_ros_setup configure_firmware.sh ping_pong --transport udp --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 8888

# build it
ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_firmware.sh
```

Next, the micro-ROS agent

```sh
# create agent ws
ros2 run micro_ros_setup create_agent_ws.sh

# build it
ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_agent.sh

source install/local_setup.bash
```

Then I setup 2 terminals, terminal 1 running the micro-ROS agent and terminal 2 running the Zephyr app.

##### Terminal 1:

```sh
$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
$ source install/local_setup.bash
$ ros2 run micro_ros_agent micro_ros_agent udp4 --port 8888
[1704166624.989047] info     | UDPv4AgentLinux.cpp | init                     | running...             | port: 8888
[1704166624.989864] info     | Root.cpp           | set_verbose_level        | logger setup           | verbose_level: 4
```

##### Terminal 2

```sh
$ source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
$ source install/local_setup.bash
$ ros2 run micro_ros_setup flash_firmware.sh
Flashing firmware for zephyr platform host
WARNING: Using a test - not safe - entropy source
*** Booting Zephyr OS build zephyr-v2.6.0  ***
Failed status on line 98: 1. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing better than spending time to summarize and articulate your question/problem and stumbling upon the solution shortly after.

It turns out that the firmware configure step has a critical message:

```sh
$ ros2 run micro_ros_setup configure_firmware.sh ping_pong --transport udp --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 8888
Configuring firmware for zephyr platform host
Configured UDP mode.
Please check firmware/zephyr_apps/microros_extensions/microros_transports.h
for configuring IP and port before build.
```

In `firmware/zephyr_apps/microros_extensions/microros_transports.h`, buried in preprocessor `#if/#elif` directives there's a set of default transport parameters, one of which specifies the IP address of the micro-ros agent, which in my case was the incorrect one `192.168.1.100`.

```c
#if defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIAL)
    #define MICRO_ROS_FRAMING_REQUIRED true
    // Set the UART used for communication. e.g. {.fd = 0} leads to UART_0 being used.
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params = {.fd = 0};
#elif defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_UDP)
    #define MICRO_ROS_FRAMING_REQUIRED false
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params = {{0,0,0}, "192.168.1.100", "8888"};
#elif defined(MICRO_ROS_TRANSPORT_SERIALUSB)
    #define MICRO_ROS_FRAMING_REQUIRED true
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params;
#endif
```

Changing that to `127.0.0.1` before building fixed my issue:

```c
    static zephyr_transport_params_t default_params = {{0,0,0}, "127.0.0.1", "8888"};
```

Proceeding to build and run the firmware shows working output!

```sh
# build
$ ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_firmware.sh

# run
$ ros2 run micro_ros_setup flash_firmware.sh
Flashing firmware for zephyr platform host
WARNING: Using a test - not safe - entropy source
*** Booting Zephyr OS build zephyr-v2.6.0  ***
Ping send seq 1734063590_1823552900
Ping send seq 2118534989_1823552900
Ping send seq 1332252450_1823552900
...
```

In addition, `micro_ros_agent` outputs:

```sh
 ros2 run micro_ros_agent micro_ros_agent udp4 --port 8888
[1704199501.102410] info     | UDPv4AgentLinux.cpp | init                     | running...             | port: 8888
[1704199501.102956] info     | Root.cpp           | set_verbose_level        | logger setup           | verbose_level: 4
[1704199502.843766] info     | Root.cpp           | create_client            | create                 | client_key: 0x176AC30B, session_id: 0x81
[1704199502.843832] info     | SessionManager.hpp | establish_session        | session established    | client_key: 0x176AC30B, address: 127.0.0.1:13752
[1704199502.855327] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_participant       | participant created    | client_key: 0x176AC30B, participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.855720] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x176AC30B, topic_id: 0x000(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.856105] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_publisher         | publisher created      | client_key: 0x176AC30B, publisher_id: 0x000(3), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.856837] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datawriter        | datawriter created     | client_key: 0x176AC30B, datawriter_id: 0x000(5), publisher_id: 0x000(3)
[1704199502.857028] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x176AC30B, topic_id: 0x001(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.857303] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_publisher         | publisher created      | client_key: 0x176AC30B, publisher_id: 0x001(3), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.857844] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datawriter        | datawriter created     | client_key: 0x176AC30B, datawriter_id: 0x001(5), publisher_id: 0x001(3)
[1704199502.858045] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x176AC30B, topic_id: 0x002(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.858254] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_subscriber        | subscriber created     | client_key: 0x176AC30B, subscriber_id: 0x000(4), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.859027] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datareader        | datareader created     | client_key: 0x176AC30B, datareader_id: 0x000(6), subscriber_id: 0x000(4)
[1704199502.859370] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x176AC30B, topic_id: 0x003(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.859639] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_subscriber        | subscriber created     | client_key: 0x176AC30B, subscriber_id: 0x001(4), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1704199502.865308] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datareader        | datareader created     | client_key: 0x176AC30B, datareader_id: 0x001(6), subscriber_id: 0x001(4)
```

And a ros2 node is listed:

```sh
$ ros2 node list
/pingpong_node
```

Along with 2 new topics

```sh
$ ros2 topic list
/microROS/ping
/microROS/pong
/parameter_events
/rosout
```